Can't clone git repo onto new server
I just setup and new server, and I am trying to clone a git repo into it. Whether I try to clone via http or ssh, I get this error message (client name obscured for privacy):
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/jillii/XXXXX.git/': Could not resolve host: gitlab.com
I had previously successfully cloned another repo onto the server - hours before this error occurred with the second repo.
It seems that maybe the server isn't connected to the internet? When I run ping google.com it returns:
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
I'm running out of tricks. Let me know if you have any ideas / anything to try.
Version:Ubuntu 22.04.4
Edit:
Output of resolvectl status
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (ens192)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 147.75.16.12
       DNS Servers: 147.75.16.11 147.75.16.12
        DNS Domain: None

When I run ping 147.75.16.12 it stalls on
PING 147.75.16.12 (147.75.16.12) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 147.75.16.12 ping statistics ---
201 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 204799ms

This is the output of ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:01:1f:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp11s0
    inet 100.69.74.12/24 brd 100.69.74.255 scope global ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe01:1f5f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Please run resolvectl status and post the output, while you're at it try to ping the address[es] listed under DNS Servers and see if they ping back,

Ah, and of course, the output of ip address

Hey @kos I updated the post with the outputs of those commands

What happens if you ping 142.250.189.206 (Google's IP)? I don't understand if 147.75.16.12 is your ISP's DNS server or if something else is providing you with that DNS server (as you don't seem to be behind a "regular" router / home network), if you can ping the address I gave you then you can try and change you DNS server to 8.8.8.8. Otherwise there might be more to this.

Thanks for entertaining my question @kos! That IP didn't work either. This is kind of a unique setup, the server can only be accessed via VPN. It's not your average DO site.. (client wanted a hyper-secure site)

Absolutely, but who's providing you with the server? Is this in housing? In any case if it's some sort of "managed" solution honestly I would refer to whoever is providing you with the server, as they have the full picture of what's going on (I mean we're glad to help if we can, but if there's some complicated setup which you aren't aware of in the first place I don't think we, meaning users on the site and you, are really in a good position to debug this). From the looks of it it seems like something isn't routing properly for some reason.

However I think we at least excluded DNS from the picture, you cannot ping stuff on the internet at all, which obviously creates the DNS resolution problem. Let me know if you have any more insights on how everything is configured and I'll try to get back at you (as long as it's not beyond my limited network expertise :))
